# Full width input in collapsed bootstrap navbar

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've modified bootstrap navbar to change the collapse breakpoint from 768px to 992px. Here's the solution I've used : stackoverflow.com/questions/18192082/bootstrap-3-navbar-collapse

**Problem** : search input is not full width under the following conditions

1) screen size is between 768px & 992px

2) collapse is toggled

I've tried `width 100%` & many other suggestions found on stackoverflow. Here's a [demo on codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aJBQqR?editors=1100)

Expectation (https://ibb.co/mwx4Qa), reality (https://ibb.co/jZAfyv)

HTML

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
  <div class="container">

    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mynav" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mynav">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#link1">Link 1</a></li>
        <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
          <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="q" placeholder="Search Google">
            <span class="input-group-btn"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button></span>
          </div>
        </form>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried to remove the container class div?

Comment: The input is full width on mobile as shown in your "expectation". If the question is solved accept an answer.

Comment: @ZimSystem "Mobile" is vague. It works for `< 768px` but breaks for `< 768px & < 992px` which is the width band that falls in the modified collapse breakpoint

Answer (score 1):

The container div is what gives the width of your navbar, so if you remove it, it should work:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">

  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mynav" aria-expanded="false">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
  </div>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mynav">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#link1">Link 1</a></li>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="q" placeholder="Search Google">
          <span class="input-group-btn"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button></span>
        </div>
      </form>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've removed the container from this codepen (http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aJBQqR?editors=1100). Still the same issue for `768px < width < 992px`

Answer (score 0):

Add this code at the bottom of your style sheet. Tested on your codepen.

```
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
  .navbar-form .input-group .input-group-btn {
    width: 1%;
  }
}
```